# Struts2 - Parameter after the action name not work for other language

Tags: java, struts2

I implement parameter after the action name like this "http://localhost:8080/webapp/book/view/abc" 
but when I send another language parameter like "http://localhost:8080/webapp/book/view/กขค" (It is Thai language)
It not work and this is my Action code.

```
@Getter @Setter String bookingNo;

@Action(value = "view/*", params = {"bookingNo", "{1}"}, results = {@Result(name = SUCCESS, location = "view.jsp")})
public String view() {

    // show something like this: &#3585;&#3586;&#3588;
    log.info("bookingNo: " + bookingNo);

    // show correct encoding value
    log.info("bookingNo after unescapeHtml: " + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(bookingNo));

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

My question is how I can set unescapeHtml or other option to get correct parameter encoding for all methods in all Action?

PS. I config URIEncode to UTF-8 in my tomcat7 already and I try to implement Interceptor but I don't know how to unescape it?

Answer (score 0):

You have UTF-8 characters. Encode them into a sequence of bytes using the
platform's default charset and decode as UTF-8 charset.

```
log.info("bookingNo: " + new String(bookingNo.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: No. I think is not about UTF-8 encoding because I can StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml to get correct value (in UTF-8)

Comment: So, what do you think UTF-8?